# How do I create a .conf file in Mac osx Lion?

Tags: macos, configuration, textedit

I'm using plain text format on text edit and I'm also storing the file as filename.conf but it always ends up getting stored as filename.conf.txt. I've even unchecked the box that says "If no extension is provided, use .txt" 
TextEdit just doesn't seem to recognize .conf as an extension?

Any help with this?

Answer (score 5):

Open TextEdit's Preferences, and switch to the **Open and Save** section. Under the **When Saving a File** panel, uncheck the `Add '.txt' extension to plain text files` option.

[image]